# how to resolve the error while installing pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch

When i am trying to install pytorch getting an error.

All my packages are upgraded to the latest version. The error is

```
setup.py::build_deps::run()
Failed to run 'bash ../tools/build_pytorch_libs.sh --use-fbgemm --use-nnpack --use-mkldnn --use-qnnpack caffe2'
```

thank you in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also got same error with older python versions. It resolved for me when i tried with latest python version 3.7

Hope this information may help you.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem so what I found is 64bit python-support PyTorch and not 32-bit python. To uninstall previous 32-bit versions and install 64bit version